# Velocity Template Engine with Spark

Tags: java, velocity, spark-java

I'm currently using spark-java to dynamically generate a website.

My folder structure is as follows:

[image: my folder structure]

```
FATAL: ResourceManager : unable to find resource 'test.vm' in any resource loader.
```

When trying to load the page however, I get this error. My code looks like this:

```
get("/helloworld", (req, res) -> {
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    model.put("test", "Hey there :)");
    return new ModelAndView(model, "test.vm");
}, new VelocityTemplateEngine());
```

Pages without Velocity are loading without problem. Can anyone help me set this up correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your velocity template file (`test.vm`) should be in the directory `src/main/resources`.

Your resources folder at the moment isn't on the `classpath` so the files can't be found.